# Weird pointer conversion in C

Tags: c, pointers, garbage-collection

I'm having trouble while writing my garbage collector in C. I give you a minimal and verifiable example for it.

The first file is in charge of dealing with the virtual machine

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t value_t;

typedef enum {
  Lb, Lb1, Lb2, Lb3, Lb4, Lb5,
  Ib, Ob
} reg_bank_t;

static value_t* memory_start;

static value_t* R[8];           

value_t* engine_get_Lb(void) { return R[Lb]; }

value_t engine_run() {
  memory_start = memory_get_start();
  for (reg_bank_t pseudo_bank = Lb; pseudo_bank <= Lb5; ++pseudo_bank)
    R[pseudo_bank] = memory_start + (pseudo_bank - Lb) * 32;
  value_t* block = memory_allocate();
}
```

Then I have the actual garbage collector, the minimized code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t value_t;

static value_t* memory_start = NULL;

void memory_setup(size_t total_byte_size) {
  memory_start = calloc(total_byte_size, 1);
}

void* memory_get_start() { return memory_start; }

void mark(value_t* base){
  value_t vbase = 0;
}

value_t* memory_allocate() {
  mark(engine_get_Lb());
  return engine_get_Lb();
}
```

Finally, minimal main is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  memory_setup(1000000);
  engine_run();

  return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm getting with gdb is that if I print `engine_get_Lb()` I get the address (value_t *) 0x7ffff490a800 while when printing `base` inside of the function `mark` I get the address (value_t *) 0xfffffffff490a800.

Any idea why this is happening?

**Complementary files that may help**

The makefile

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

SRCS=src/engine.c   \
     src/main.c     \
     src/memory_mark_n_sweep.c

CFLAGS_COMMON=-std=c11 -fwrapv 

CLANG_SAN_FLAGS=-fsanitize=address

# Clang warning flags
CLANG_WARNING_FLAGS=-Weverything        \
                    -Wno-format-nonliteral  \
                    -Wno-c++98-compat       \
                    -Wno-gnu-label-as-value

# Flags for debugging:
CFLAGS_DEBUG=${CFLAGS_COMMON} -g ${CLANG_SAN_FLAGS} ${CLANG_WARNING_FLAGS}

# Flags for maximum performance:
CFLAGS_RELEASE=${CFLAGS_COMMON} -O3 -DNDEBUG

CFLAGS=${CFLAGS_DEBUG}

all: vm

vm: ${SRCS}
    mkdir -p bin
    clang ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${SRCS} -o bin/vm
```

File with instructions .asm

```
5c190000  RALO(Lb,25)
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue with GDB? When using printf everything looks alright - maybe you told GDB somehow to use 64bit in mark?

Comment: You already posted the same question an hour ago (now deleted). Why did you not edit the original?

Comment: You see it in your history!

Comment: Delete the other one if it's worse quality. I can't reproduce your assertion - can you post exactly what you test in the example? That will remove the GDB dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value_t* memory_allocate() {
  mark(engine_get_Lb());
  return engine_get_Lb();
}
```

`engine_get_Lb` is not declared before use. It is assumed by the compiler to return `int`, per an **antiquated and dangerous rule of the C language**. It was deprecated in the C standard for quite some time, and now is finally removed.

Create a header file with declarations of all your global functions, and `#include` it in all your source files.

Your compiler should have at least warned you about this error at its default settings. If it did, you should have read and completely understood the warnings before continuing. If it didn't, consider an upgrade. If you cannot upgrade, permanently add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to your compilation flags. Consider also `-Wpedantic` and `-std=c11`.